# I cannot drag and add elements such as "label" into a widget in pyside2 designer (MacBook)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-creator, qt-designer, pyside2

I cannot drag and add elements such as "label" into a widget in pyside2 designer (MacBook)

I installed python3.7.7
and wrote this:

```
pip3 install PySide2
```

and searched "Designer". I clicked python3.7.7 > PySide2 > Designer
It is work but I cannot drag and add elements

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Once Designer is opened, do you create a new form (Main window, Widget, Dialog)? If so, then you're trying to drag elements from the widget list and you cannot drop the element on the new form, is that right?

Comment: I can create widget but I can't drag elements into a widget. Yeah, Rıght

Comment: It seems to be a recently [reported bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86786) for macOS, it seems that it has been fixed with Qt 5.15.2, but you need to wait for its release (it should be sometime in November), otherwise revert to the previous 5.15.0 version instead. I believe you can either uninstall and then install using `pip3 install PySide2==5.15.0` or with `pip3 install --upgrade PySide==5.15.0`

Comment: thx! I owe you. I may have lost 2 days because of this. I will no longer hesitate to throw questions in stackoverflow

Comment: No problem. For future reference, whenever you have a *very* unexpected behavior, you can also try googling search queries including "qtbug", as that's how I found out about this issue.

Comment: I definitely searched on google but could not find the result. Thank you again for telling me how to search. Soon I will be embarking on a professional application design. I couldn't have done it without you.

Comment: Well, good luck then :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a recently [reported bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86786) for macOS, it seems that it has been fixed with Qt 5.15.2, but you need to wait for its release (it should be sometime in November), otherwise revert to the previous 5.15.0 version instead. I believe you can either uninstall and then install using `pip3 install PySide2==5.15.0` or with `pip3 install --upgrade PySide==5.15.0`

Thank you! [@musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante)